# regex for 6 digits before and 2 digits after decimal

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I need a regex in which decimal is optional. If decimal is there then there can be max 6 digits before and max 2 digits after decimal. If decimal is not there then max of 6 digits is valid.

Regex tested :**`^\d{0,6}\.?\d{1,2}$`**

The above regex allows max of 8 digits without decimal. How can I change according to my needs so that if there is no decimal then it would take max of 6 digits?

**VALID CASES**

```
123456.12  
21231  
123456  
15465.43  
23.34  
6.45  
.12
```

**INVALID CASES**

```
12345678  
123456.331
```

Comment: there is a limit of 6 digits(max) before decimal and 2 digits (max) after decimal

Comment: @Pshemo  yes ".12" is valid .

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
^\d{0,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oL9kE8/4

Just make the `(\.\d{1,2})` decimal part optional.`?`

Comment: If I want to create a modular method to perform this check, is it possible to construct a dynamic regex where I supply how many digits before/after the decimal are allowed?

Comment: @MukeshBhojwani yes just use format and provide values

Comment: This works for me '^\\d{0,'+integerLength+'}(\\.\\d{1,'+precision+'})?$'